# What is resolution ((in FOL))?

Tags: lo.logic, resolution

I'm searching for an **authoritative definition** of resolution (logic resolution).

Preferably on a reference freely available on the Internet (so I can read it right now).

If this is too broad then resolution for first order logic.

Thank you.

Comment: Too basic for this site.

Comment: Try googling "resolution proof system".

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I think you didn't understand the question, please let me know any detail that may not be clear. Thank you.

Comment: @Trylks, he wikipedia articles for resolution http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic) and inference rules explain all these topics. Do you want a definition of resolution or to know whether it has certain properties? Your context does not help because both statements about resolution are vague. I don't understand the focus on "new theorems".

Comment: See also this discussion: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16572/is-propositional-resolution-a-complete-proof-system?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike the question you threaten for inference rule, this has a nice, simple answer:

> Robinson (1965) A machine-oriented logic based on the resolution principle. *Journal of the ACM*.

Resolution only applies to a subfragment of FOL, the Horn clauses, that lack disjunction and existential quantification, but combined with Herbrandisation, this is sufficient to encode satisfiability in the following sense: for any formula of FOL, we can find a Horn clause such that each is satisfiable if the other is.

Resolution is related to cut-elimination, but is more efficient.

Extending resolution to the whole of FOL requires a more sophistcated approach to unification than Robinson's algorithm.  Uniform provability offers a technique for reading off such a computational mechanism from a cleaned-up proof theory of intuitionistic logic, higher-order unification, and the double-negation translation.